# Crystal Reports 11 - Formula. 2 Groups

Tags: crystal-reports

What is happening is that I have a formula that is in the Group Header 2. What it is doing is SUM all of Group 2 (Invoice ID)

```
formula = SUM({Commissions_ttx.CommissionAmount},{Commissions_ttx.arpARInvoiceID})
```

Group 1 is EmpID

Group 2 is InvoiceID

It is skipping over the Group of 1 instead is getting all of the InvoiceID. There can be more than 1 employee on this. So the totals are doubling.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in the sum function you need to do something like

```
   SUM({Commissions_ttx.arpARInvoiceID},{your group name})
```

if you have multiple sum values you need to get the sum of each group separately into 2 variables the the sum of both values e.g.

```
  variable1 = SUM({field1},{Group1})
  variable2 = SUM({field2},{Group2})
  variable3 = tonumber(variable1 + variable2)
```